# Vertex coordinates - Blender

Tags: python, vertices

is there any way that I can convert vertex coordinates from Blender so I can use them in ACad to redraw a face from blender object. May by with Python help

Comment: Do you mean exporting the model? To ACad, Autocad?

Comment: I don't want to export the whole model, only one face. I am looking for a way to use vertex coordinates in ACad,